# renewing account before it expires

Tags: playstation-plus

I had about 2 months left on my account, and recently I added another 12 months to my account. I was wondering, do the months stack up or does it continue with the two months and **then** use the 12 months?

Comment: They stack. I once bought 2 x 12 month subscriptions and I had PSPlus for 2 years.

Answer (score 8):

They do stack.

If you have a look at the expiration date for any PS Plus content you've downloaded, you'll see it has been expanded by 1 year exactly.

On **PS3**, navigate to any PS Plus game, press [image: Triangle], select `Information`, then scroll down to `Expires`.

On **PS4**, navigate to any PS Plus game, press <kbd>OPTIONS</kbd>, select `Information`, then scroll down to `Valid Period (End)` or to `Remaining Time`.

On **PS Vita**, touch and hold any PS Plus game, select `Information`, and see `Expires` or `Remaining Time`.

---

Due to DDoS attacks taking down SEN in December, Sony has decided to gift 5 days of PS Plus to whomever had a valid subscription in 2014-12-25 (December 25 of 2014). Because of that, it is possible the expiration date for your game may have been extended by a year and 5 days.

Comment: How did you insert the triangle button? That's pretty cool!

Comment: I used the markup for image insertion and used [an image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PlayStationTriangle.svg) I found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DualShock). If in doubt, you can always click on "edit" to see how a post has been formatted ;)